# visual studio code change file language shortcut key

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

**vscode change file language**

I usually create new file and paste some code. And it always starts with `plaintext` as file language.

Is there a shortcut key to change the file programming language from plain text to what I want.

What is the shortcut key to change language in vscode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl + K</kbd> +<kbd>M</kbd> to show the choose file language list